# How to get more information from a InputStremed file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, inputstream

If I'm using the `InputStream` to receive a file, like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream
```

How can get more information about the file?

I can easily convert a Stream into a phisical File, but for example, **how would I know the file extension in use**?

```
string fileIn = @"C:\Temp\inputStreamedFile.xxx"; // What extension?

using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileIn))
{
    Stream f = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[f.Length];
    f.Read(bytes, 0, (int)f.Length);
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

---

The idea behind this is because using `HttpPostedFileBase` I always get null:

```
public ContentResult Send(HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload, string email)
{
    // Get file stream and save it

    // Get File in stream
    string fileIn = Path.Combine(uploadsPath, uniqueIdentifier),
           fileOut = Path.Combine(convertedPath, uniqueIdentifier + ".pdf");

    // Verify that the user selected a file
    if (fileToUpload != null && fileToUpload.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileToUpload.FileName);
        fileIn = String.Concat(fileIn, fileExtension);

        fileToUpload.SaveAs(fileIn);
    }

    // TODO: Add Convert File to Batch

    return Content("File queued for process with id: " + uniqueIdentifier);
}
```

and this is what I'm sending from the command line:

```
$ curl --form email='mail@domain.com' --form fileToUpload='C:\temp\MyWord.docx' http://localhost:64705/send/
File queued for process with id: 1d777cc7-7c08-460c-8412-ddab72408123
```

the variable `email` is filled up correctly, but `fileToUpload` is always null.

P.S. **This does not happen** if I use a form to upload the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I found was using curl... I was forgetting the `@` sign that mention that the uploaded form would be encoded as `multipart/form-data`.

The correct curl command to use `HttpPostedFileBase` would be:

```
$ curl --form email='mail@domain.com' 
       --form fileToUpload=@'C:\temp\MyWord.docx' 
       http://localhost:64705/send/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if this doesn't help, but why use InputStream to get uploaded file(s) ?

This is what I usually do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files) {
    String physicalPath = "c:\\whatever";
    foreach (var file in files) {
        String extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(physicalPath + "\\" + file.FileName);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: because I want to use this with cURL, PowerShell and other scripting languages, I don't want a File Upload Page. An example is to use as a calDav parser, all email clients send the `.ics` file as the input stream, though the library I'm using for that can read directly from a `Stream`, but now I'm trying to make a simple PDF Converter to use in a command line.

Comment: @balexandre, as long as your client supports `multipart/form-data` (which respected clients such as cURL do) you could use a `HttpPostedFileBase` without any problems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no file name anywhere to be found if you stream some data directly to the server. Being a stream you can't expect a file name, it's just binary data, not necessarily a file.

Comment: @Darin using `curl --form email="mail@domain.com" --form fileToUpload="c:\temp\myWord.docx" http://localhost:1112/send/"` **I always get** `null` in my `public ContentResult Send(HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload, string email)` but not in `email`, that's why I wanted to use the `InputStream` as I do get the file there (well, at least the ÌnputStream` contains something...).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the info about posted file from `<input type="file" />`. But actually it's used a bit different way to upload files in asp.net mvc [check out here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Comment: I know how to upload files in MVC, I just want to use the InputStream.